# Java Netbeans BeanCreationException

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, glassfish

Im trying to deploy netbeans java ee project ( maven + hibernate + JSF ) on glassfish

Im getting error below. My database configuration is ok ( double checked from several apps ), and database itself is ok and online.

```
SEVERE: WebModule[/web-0.1-SNAPSHOT]PWC1275: 
  Exception sending context initialized event to listener
  instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
  name 'txManager' defined in ServletContext resource 
  [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
      Property 'sessionFactory' is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem by setting correct java executable in glassfish properties. Ty for help !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to define the sessionFactory in your applicationContext.xml.  See this [forum post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/60666/Application-Frameworks/define-Hibernate-SessionFactory-with-Spring) for more details.

Comment: I have file spring-datasources imported to appliacationContext.xml
It contains 

 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="c3p0LocalDataSource" /><property name="namingStrategy">
   <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
  </property>
  <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop> {...}

Comment: i believe it is something with IDE or glassfish

Comment: im sure because same app is developed on several other machines and they are running correct